# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

> Configuration validation exception: AWS Elastic Beanstalk could not communicate with Amazon EC2 to determine whether to create a custom security group for Elastic Load Balancing.

When creating an AWS Elastic Beanstalk application, I get this error while trying to proceed with "review and launch". I am new to this. Please help.

Comment: It seems like instance is not accessible. Check the security group rules.

Comment: Where can I find that?

Comment: In ec2 section in web console check tge security groups and its config

Comment: I don't remember visiting anything related to EC2.. uh

Comment: When you provision resources Elastic Beanstalk it provisions different services which you can find through tags linked with the environment. These you can also see from web console

Comment: Is that automatic or manual?

Comment: Most of the things happen automatically with the ElasticBeanstalk but some of them are semi automatic based on the parameters you select.

Comment: How do I create an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on **Services>>** Under **Compute>>** Select **EC2>>** if it show this message **"Your service sign-up is almost complete!"**, check back after some few hours, your app should be ready.

Comment: I've been getting that message for 4 days now. It doesnt just go away on its own . Support might be your only option. Though they havnt been able to help me yet. They have confirmed that my account is actually fully set up.

Answer (score 7):

I got this error when trying to set up the test application shortly after signing up for the AWS free tier.

I checked into the EC2 dash board and my account hadn't been fully set up yet.  It said it could take up to 24 hours.  I waited about 2 hours and everything worked as expected.